# PHP регулярное выражение пароля (Вид: "0-9 a-z A-Z")

Tags: php

Как составить регулярное выражение для проверки пароля который должен состоять из 0-9 a-z A-Z и иметь как минимум одну цифру, одну маленькую и одну большую букву?

Comment: Длинной 12-25 символов

Comment: Для чего диктовать пользователю, какой у него должен быть пароль? Минимальная длина 12 - это жесть. Выдавайте сертификаты вместо пароля.

Comment: Сертификаты есть само собой)

Answer (score 2):

Вот один из [вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot) английской версии стека   `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{12,25}$`

`(?=.*[a-z])` - маленькая буква
`(?=.*[A-Z])` - большая
`(?=.*\d)` - число
`[a-zA-Z\d]` - всё остальное буквы и цифры
`{12,25}` - от 12 до 25

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/SvvJ9W/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
^\S*(?=\S{12,25})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$
```

- (?=\S{12,25}): задает лимит паролю 12-25 символов
- (?=\S*[a-z]): содержит хотя бы одну маленькую букву
- (?=\S*[A-Z]): содержит хотя бы одну большую букву
- (?=\S*[\d]): и хотя бы одну цифру

Если понимаете английский есть хорошая статья и очень интересные обсуждения по этому поводу, собственно там и была эта регулярка, работает хорошо, сам пользовался.

Источник: https://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: Какое сообщение об ошибке выводить, если пользователь вдруг введёт в свой пароль пробел, а то и два? И что действительно означает число 25 в регулярке?

Comment: Любое выводить, вам же нужна регулярка для проверки, если хотите выводить пользователю что именно он не так ввел в пароле тогда надо разбивать регулярку на несколько и тогда будете точно знать в чем причина, 12-25 это минимальная и максимальная длинна пароля

Comment: Разве `\S*` в начале и конце не говорят вам о том, что максимальной длины тут нет? Почему пробел в пароле должен быть ошибкой?

Comment: \S* matches any non-whitespace character. Можно же зайти на любой сервис и проверить  что тут написано и как работает.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MjHwbp/1